# Multiplying Numbers in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I want to be able to multiply two numbers taken from two columns and display it in the third column.

I have two columns where the user types in the numbers and a third one where it automatically multiplies the numbers as the user hits enter.

But I have 100 textboxes like these and I do not want to write the code for every single one of them.

Is there any way to perform this operation as you would in excel?
It is really easy to do it in excel.

Here is what I have to write for every single textbox:

```
Private Sub Text03_GotFocus()
Text05.Value = Val(Text03.Value) * Val(Text04.Value) * 12
End Sub

Private Sub Text03_LostFocus()
Text05.Value = Val(Text03.Value) * Val(Text04.Value) * 12
End Sub

Private Sub Text04_GotFocus()
Text05.Value = Val(Text03.Value) * Val(Text04.Value) * 12
End Sub

Private Sub Text04_LostFocus()
Text05.Value = Val(Text03.Value) * Val(Text04.Value) * (12)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, it would be simpler to open your form in design view, then open the property sheet for your `Text05` text box and use this as the `Control Source` property (on the `Data` tab of the property sheet):

```
= Val([Text03]) * Val([Text04]) * 12
```

Then you should not need VBA code for got/lost focus events.  Access will *automagically* update `Text05` whenever the values in `Text03` or `Text04` change.